# Solving quadratic equations over finite fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, quadratics, finite-fields, quotient-spaces

How does one solve the equations $x^2-3=0$ and $x^2+x-1=0$ in $\Bbb{F}_7[x] / (x^2-5)$?

Not sure how do do it, I know there is a solution for both, but I don't see how to get there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\alpha\in\Bbb{F}_7[x]/(x^2-5)$ such that $\alpha^2=5$. Then for any $c\in\Bbb{F}_7$ we have
$$(c\alpha)^2=c^2\alpha^2=5c^2,$$
so for which $c\in\Bbb{F}_7$ is $c\alpha$ a root of $x^2-3$?

More generally every element of $k$ can be written as $a\alpha+b$ for some $a,b\in\Bbb{F}_7$. Plugging this expression into your polynomials yields two equations for $a$ and $b$, which aren't hard to solve in the quadratic case.

Comment: Thanks a lot, just to make sure can you do it with the first one ?

Comment: You want to solve $5c^2\equiv3\pmod7$, which gives $c\equiv\pm3\pmod7$.

Comment: Alright I get there, but what is the final answer supposed to look like ?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by 'solving' $x^2-3$. I would say the solutions are $3\alpha$ and $-3\alpha$, which fortunately does not depend on our original choice of $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x^2-3=(x^2-5)+2$ and in this field is equal to 2. Idem with the other polynomial

Comment: Though it is written somewhat ambiguously, I believe the **x** and *x* are not the same in this question, as otherwise there is nothing to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\omega$ a root of $x^-5=0$. A root $\;\xi$ of $x^2-3=0$ must satisfy $N(\xi)=3$. If we try $\xi=a\omega$, we have $\;N(a\omega)=a^2N(\omega)=5a^2$, whence the equation $5a^2=3$. As $5^{-1}=3$, this implies $a^2=3^2$, whence $a=\pm 3$. So the solutions are
$$\xi=\pm 3\omega.$$